# Slick slide- how set nextSlide in beforeChange

Tags: javascript, slick.js

How can i change nextSlide in slick slider in beforeChange

```
$(blockName)
   .slick().on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide,  nextSlide){
   nextSlide = 9; 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are trying to manipulate the slide with that index. If that's the case (as it was with me), you can use something like this:

```
var nextPanel = $('[data-slick-index=' + nextSlide + ']');
```

Then you can add classes and such as so:

```
$(nextPanel).addClass('active-panel');
```

Hope that helps!